# JFreeChart to represent 3D data in a 2D graph using colourmaps

Tags: java, graph, dataset, jfreechart, renderer

I'm currently trying to use `JFreeChart` to represent 3D data in a 2D graph.

Essentially, I have a 2d array called `data[i][j]`. The `i` and `j` represent the `y` and `x` coordinates where I want to plot. The value of `data[i][j]` represents a frequency value, which I want to represent in the graph as a colour.

I'm not entirely sure what something like this is called, but it would look something like this:

[image]

Now I have been trying to do this using `XYBlockRenderer`, however I am having issues with defining the dataset. I am trying to use `DefaultXYZDataset`, but I'm really confused at how to even define the data here.

Can someone explain how to use the `DefaultXYZDataset` to accomplish such a task?

```
DefaultXYZDataset dataset = new DefaultXYZDataset();

Concentration.dataoutHeight = Concentration.dataout[0].length;

System.out.println(Concentration.dataoutHeight);
System.out.println(ImageProcessor.MAXCBVINT);
double[][] data = new double[3][ImageProcessor.MAXCBVINT];


for (int i = 0; i < Concentration.dataoutHeight; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ImageProcessor.MAXCBVINT; j++) {
        data[0][j] = j;//x value
        data[1][j] = i;//y value
        data[2][j] = Concentration.dataout[j][i][0];//Colour
    }
    dataset.addSeries(i, data);

}
NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis("Intensity");
xAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
xAxis.setLowerMargin(0.0);
xAxis.setUpperMargin(0.0);
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Distance to Closest Blood Vessel (um)");
yAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
yAxis.setLowerMargin(0.0);
yAxis.setUpperMargin(0.0);
XYBlockRenderer renderer = new XYBlockRenderer();
PaintScale scale = new GrayPaintScale(0, 10000.0);
renderer.setPaintScale(scale);
renderer.setBlockHeight(1);
renderer.setBlockWidth(1);
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Surface Plot", plot);
chart.removeLegend();
chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Surface Map - "
    + (Concentration.testing ? "TESTING using "
    + Concentration.testfile : currentFile.getName()), chart);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe. [`XYBlockChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Represent them as 3d
   [3D Lib for JFreeChart](http://www.jzy3d.org/)
2. You need to use the class : [XYBlockRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBlockRenderer.html) which does exactly what you are asking. You can download the JFreeChart demo collection where the code for this is given.
   (source code of class [here](http://dgpf.sourceforge.net/scripts/source/source.php?file=org.jfree.experimental.chart.demo.XYBlockChartDemo1.java))
   There is also [this](http://www.plainagile.com/archives/215) full code example with 4D very similar.